# mysql error when trying to add foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm building a database in MySql using MySql 5.6.14 and MySql Workbench 6.0.7.  I have an Orders table and 2 details tables.  I'm trying to set the 2 details tables to have a foreign key to the orders table OrderNumber column.

The main orders table can be created like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`PO` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`OrderTotal`,`PO`)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There are other columns, but none are referenced here.

The other 2 tables are similar in their structure and look basically like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `orderdetail` (
 `PO` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `EnteredID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`PO`,`EnteredID`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Every time I try adding a foreign key to the tables though, I get:

> ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

This is followed by:

> ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.
>
> ERROR 1050: Table 'orderdetail' already exists

From what I've researched, Error 1050 is meaningless here and is an error thrown when the previous query didn't work.  Others have had issues with using the wrong DB type, having a foreign key with the same name, capitalization issues, and mismatching data types.  I'm using the InnoDB engine on all my tables, my MySQL server is set to be all lower case and case insensitive, the types match exactly, and there is no other foreign key with that name.

So I'm at a loss at why I'm having so much trouble creating a couple of foreign keys.

Comment: Please post the statement you are using to add the FK constraints.

Comment: Are you trying to create a table when one already exists?

Comment: To Michael Berkowski, I'm trying to do this through MySQL Workbenches UI.  From Alter Table->Foreign Keys Tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to have an index on the referenced table for that column.  I thought the primary key index would have sufficed, but I guess not.